# matlabs linprog too slow

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am working on a matlab application for which I need much improved speed.  I am using linprog to solve a 2-constraint linear program with around 10,000 variables bounded by zero and one.  Linprog is extremely slow for my application.  Is there any way I can reformulate to improve speed?  Or do you perhaps know of some matlab-compatible shareware (I'm on a tight budget) that would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind an implementation that is not in matlab but interfaced using MEX, maybe glpk and glpkmex can help

http://glpkmex.sourceforge.net/

Alternatively, lpsolve may be able to help also but it's not as good as glpk library for large scale problems:
http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/MATLAB.htm

If you can get your hands on it, IBM ILOG CPLEX is actually one of the best for large scale problems. There is an interface to matlab (http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimizer/connectors/), and you can try to get an extended trial version if you do not have a licence.

In special cases it may be possible to simplify your problem significantly by looking at the coefficients in the objective function and determining which constraint will be active depending on what your constraints are.  Variables which do not participate in active constraints can be set at either min value or max value (0 or 1, as per your description) depending on whether their coefficients in the objective function are positive or negative , assuming you are minimizing your objective function. If you're doing maximization then do the reverse. This shaves off the number of variables =).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a linear program with box constraints (may be called bound constraints) to me. Have you set those box constraints properly? See the [reference](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/optim/ug/linprog.html) for more information.